# Adding array of UIImage in a UIViewController with some alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimage, storyboard

I just started my first project in iOS, recently I have encountered a problem in the UI when i receive it from the designer.
The expected output is shown as below and i can do most of it without any problem. 
[image: Expected Design]

Now the problem came when I am about to implement this :
[image: Design that required helps/ guidances]

As the number of colour varies depending on item, I cannot add it like what I did for the share and love button I have no idea how can i implement something like this, I have look through the Object Library in the storyboard and cannot find any that can produce the output as expected .Any helps and guides are much apprecited!

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your question.

Comment: @AshokLondhe hi, I have the texture with several colours displayed below the item image ( 4 colors in this case) . In both design and code, how can i achieve the same or similar output as shown in the diagram. Noted that the above diagram is just a mockup, i am trying to produce the design in XCode